# Changing tmux prefix on Mac (Mojave) to C+a captures Cmd+left

Tags: macos, mac, tmux, macos-mojave

I'm relatively new to Mac (coming from Linux) and in my tmux.conf file, I have the following:

```
unbind C-b
set -g prefix C-a
bind C-a send-prefix
```

which works as you would expect with one hick-up.  Command+left-arrow, which performs the same function as 'Home' on Windows/Linux, is somehow treated like the tmux prefix.

If I type:

```
command + left-arrow
command + left-arrow
```

Then it works, but just a single press of cmd+left acts as the prefix.

If I remove those lines entirely, cmd+left works fine, so I may just go back to ctrl+b as the prefix (I came from using screen, thus opting for ctrl+a)

Any possible ideas on what might be causing this or is this perhaps just a bug with tmux?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up fixing this in iterm2 by setting CMD+left to send the escape sequence "OH" and CMD+right to send the escape sequence "OF" (that's capital 'o' , not zero)

Now everything works in iterm2.  It's still an issue in the default Terminal shipped with MacOS, but I'm calling this solved well enough.